# How to order these lines for a highscore table in Python

Tags: python

I have the following in a text file:

```
('bob', '10')
('Ben', '10')
('Ben', '9')
('Ben', '8')
('Ben', '2')
('Ben', '6')
('Ben', '5')
('Ben', '5')
('Ben', '3')
('Ben', '2')
```

I would like to reorder it so that it is ordered by numbers going down, so that I can print them off in a high score table, however I cannot work out how to do this. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please consider posting some code and explaining where you are stuck...

Comment: Wait, why are the numbers strings in all the lines but the first?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`ast.literal_eval`](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to parse the tuples and then pass them to `sorted`:

```
import ast
from operator import itemgetter

def parse_item(s):
  name, score = ast.literal_eval(s)
  return name, int(score)

with open("infile", "r") as infile:
  items = [parse_item(line.strip()) for line in infile]

for item in sorted(items, key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True):
  print item
```

Or the concise but confusing way:

```
print ''.join(sorted(open('infile'), key=lambda l: -int(ast.literal_eval(l)[1]))),
```

Comment: @Ben: Well, if you have `items` built up already like described in my code (you should really use `with ... as inFile`), you can just do `names, values = zip(*items)`. But depending on what you want to do, you can maybe just keep them as a list of tuples and iterate through them in parallel using `for name, score in items:`

Comment: @Ben: Impossible to tell what's wrong without seeing the input file. With your example, it works perfectly for me: http://paste.pocoo.org/show/587794/

Comment: Never mind, I believe I have fixed it, slight error in my input file. Thanks

Comment: @Ben: It would be better if you kept the scores as integers in the input file, so you can spare the call to `int()`. You could essentially drop the `parse_item` function then, as it would reduce to a simple `ast.literal_eval`.

Comment: @Ben: This code is just unreadable. I also don't understand the question, sorry. Please consider a new question for that (seemingly new) problem.

Answer (score 1):

If `l` is the list of tuples, the following will do the sorting:

```
sorted(l, key=lambda(name,score):int(score), reverse=True)
```

Reading the file is left as an exercise for the reader :)

Answer (score 0):

If you even suspect that your highscore list is going to get more complicated at some point in the future, you probably should stop using a list of tuples, and use a list of purpose-made class instances instead.

Anyway, if you stick with tuples, just convert the str numbers to int's, and reverse the order of the two fields of the tuples to get something that'll sort.

A class might look like:

```
class Highscore:
   def __init__(self, name, score):
      self.name = name
      self.score = score

   def __cmp__(self, other):
      return -cmp(self.score, other.score)
```